Arrows above thicken portion of curve
I have the following code and I want to plot the arrows above the pink thicken portion but to keep their order.
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.fillbetween}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,bending}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
    on each segment/.style={
        decorate,
        decoration={
            show path construction,
            moveto code={},
            lineto code={
                \path [#1]
                (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) -- (\tikzinputsegmentlast);
            },
            curveto code={
                \path [#1] (\tikzinputsegmentfirst)
                .. controls
                (\tikzinputsegmentsupporta) and (\tikzinputsegmentsupportb)
                ..
                (\tikzinputsegmentlast);
            },
            closepath code={
                \path [#1]
                (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) -- (\tikzinputsegmentlast);
            },
        },
    },
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}[scale=2]
        \draw[smooth, tension=1, name path=curve] 
            plot coordinates{(0.6,0.9) (1,2.2) (2,-0.5) (1,-1) (1,1) (1,2.3) (1.3,-0.9)}
        [postaction={on each segment={draw,-{stealth[black,bend]}}}];
\draw[name path=line, smooth] (0.8,-0.5) -- (1.8,1.8);
\draw[thick,pink, intersection segments={of=curve and line, sequence={L2 -- L3 -- R3}}] -- cycle;

        \fill[name intersections={of=curve and line}]
            (intersection-3) circle[radius=1pt] node[right] {$p_1$}
            (intersection-1) circle[radius=1pt] node[right] {$p_2$};

        
        
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}



Are you sure that you really want show path construction or do you just want arrow tips?

The decoration show path construction will draw arrow tips together with the path, so it is probably not what you want. Rather, if I understood you correctly, you want to just decorate the path with arrow tips which can be achieved much easier.
Also, in order to first draw the path, then redraw a part of it and only then add the arrow tips, you need to save the path for reuse. This can be achieved using the spath3 library:
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.fillbetween, decorations.markings, bending, spath3}

\tikzset{
    on each segment/.style={
        decorate,
        decoration={
            markings,
            mark=between positions .01 and 1 step .08 with {\arrow{#1}},
        },
    },
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}[scale=2]
    
        \draw[smooth, tension=1, name path=curve, spath/save=curve] 
            plot coordinates{
                (0.6,0.9) (1,2.2) (2,-0.5) (1,-1) (1,1) (1,2.3) (1.3,-0.9)
            };
        
        \draw[name path=line, smooth] (0.8,-0.5) -- (1.8,1.8);
        
        \draw[thick, pink, intersection segments={
            of=curve and line, sequence={L2 -- L3 -- R3}
        }] -- cycle;

        \path[spath/use=curve, postaction={
            on each segment={stealth[black, bend]},
        }];

        \fill[name intersections={of=curve and line}]
            (intersection-3) circle[radius=1pt] node[right] {$p_1$}
            (intersection-1) circle[radius=1pt] node[right] {$p_2$};
        
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}



Great, indeed that is what I wanted. Thank you!
